# I'm looking for some code that can help me put together a Market Cap index

Tags: r

I am attempting to aggregate raw data from different shares (1990 - 2023) to construct Market Cap indices.

As a university student, I'm endeavoring to create sector-specific Market Cap indices. I've gathered what I believe to be all the necessary data, but I may require assistance with the code itself. I have specific data frames for prices and market capitalizations, with dates in the first column spanning from January 2, 1990, to December 5, 2023, and company names as column headers. Under each column, I have the relevant price or market cap data. However, the issue arises from companies listing and delisting during this period, resulting in a fluctuating group of companies. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I'm more than willing to provide additional details if necessary.

Below is an example of the code I tried to run. Each dataframe (Energy_Px and Energy_Mc) consists of 8484 observations and 17 variables, with this being the smallest dataframe, I am trying to work with. My objective is to create an index where, for the same period, I can obtain a relevant Market Cap index value for each day.

One of the challenges I'm facing is my limited proficiency in coding, as it's not the focus of my degree, and I'm learning as I go. I struggle with understanding the intricacies of the code, and there's a high likelihood of human error.

```r
Energy_MC1 <- indexComp(
  Energy_Mc, Energy_Px, vol = NULL, weighting = "market", weighting.all = "market",
  ic = "AIC", eval.seq = c("sequential"), optimum = c ("global"), start.const = 1,
  step = 1 fixed.value = NULL, base.value = 1000, derivation.period = 1, 
  derivation.ic = 3, "Date")
```

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and any errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))` into a [code block]), and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: The libraries I have used are the following (library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(xts)
library(zoo)
library(openxlsx)
library(writexl)
library(IndexConstruction)
library(KernSmooth)
library(fGarch)
library(lubridate)
library(RcppBDT)) and i have converted the df to xts, but I keep receiving the following error (Error in indexComp(df_mx, df_px, vol = NULL, weighting = "market", weighting.all = "market",  : 
  The data for 'price' and 'market' have to be in the format 'xts'. Please check the R library 'xts' to convert the data.)